# How to convert selected time value to proper time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, ionic-framework, momentjs

I am using a timepicker component for ionic called [ionic-timepicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker) and in the documentation the selected time value is an epoch.

The callback to get the value is this:

```
var ipObj1 = {
    callback: function (val) {      //Mandatory
      if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Time not selected');
      } else {
        var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
        console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), 'H :', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'M');
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem here is for example I chose 2:00 PM in the timepicker, the `selectedTime` value is `Thu Jan 01 1970 22:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)` and I wish to only get the exact `2:00 PM` value.

Second, why does the `selectedTime` variable contains Jan 01 1970? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use the library [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

let date = moment(new Date()).format('LT');

// Outputs: '10:42 AM'
```

Different formats can be found in the documentation.

The reason you date is falling back to 1 Jan 1970 is because you are not setting any date at all. By default date/moment objects fallback to the beginning of the Unix timestamp.

Comment: I'm actually using it now. My code is moment(selectedTime).format('LT') and when I select 2:00 PM in the timepicker, I get 10:00 PM using moment(selectedTime).format('LT')

Comment: Perhaps because you multiply it by 1000 ? Why you do this in the first place ? Have you tried setting the pickers' format to  24 hours ?

Comment: I tried to remove the multiplied by 1000 and I need a 12 hr format because I am from the Philippines but I still get incorrect values. Thanks anyway